# Make adb monitor for an intent?

Tags: android, adb

Like the headline suggestes I would like to make adb wait for an intent, is that possible?

I have an app that writes a file to filesystem and I would like to pull it with adb once its done, problem is I dont know how long it will take on each device.

Is there a way to make adb wait for an activity to close or wait for an intent?
Or maybe someone has a better idea of how to achieve what I want to do?

I have read through all of the pm and am API and there doesnt seem to be anything useful in there.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to wait intent by using adb.

How about using tmp file to check file writing completed?

1. from your app, create completed.trx file if target file writing completed
2. write simple scripts to check completed.trx file (routinely) by using adb shell command
3. if completed.trx exist, get written file by adb pull and delete completed.trx file by adb shell

Comment: I added -temp to my file and renamed it to remove -temp when done, is there a special meaning to .trx?

Comment: Transaction file. your solution looks simpler.